# Ajax function not working properly for deleting without refreshing page

Tags: django, ajax, django-views

I am working on a problem where I need to delete an entry in database without refreshing the list page. However, with the ajax function and view that I have created, the data is getting deleted but success function is not changing to true.The list page is displayed as it is, and on manually refreshing the deleted data is not displayed. Also, since I am new to ajax I have less idea about what to put in data dictionary in ajax for deleting.What am I doing wrong in the code? Please help me in doing so without page refresh.(I need to stay on the centrelist page).Thanks in advance.

```
<script>

$(document).on('click','#delete',function(){
 var a ;
 a=confirm("Do you really want to delete the user?");
if(a==true){
 var url = "{% url 'NewApp:centredelete' pk=1%}"
 var id = $(this).attr('name')
 $.ajax(
{
    type:"GET",
    url: url.replace('1',id),
    data:{
          delete:true
    },
    success: function( data )
    {
        if(data.success == true){
           $(id).remove();

         }

     }
     })}
});
</script>
```

views.py

```
def CentreDeleteView(request, pk):
data = {'success': False}
centre = Centre.objects.get(pk=pk)
print(centre)
if request.method == 'GET':
    try:
        if centre:
            centre.delete()
            data['success'] = True

        else:
            data['success'] = False
            data['error'] = "unsuccessful!"
    except Centre.DoesNotExist:
        return redirect('/NewApp/centrelist')
return JsonResponse(json.dumps(data))
```

Comment: not related but if you are using `JsonResponse` then you don't have to use `json.dumps`.

Comment: What does 'var id = $(this).attr('name')' return? Have you tried to use $(id).remove(); with an actual ID?

Comment: name= modelname.id in my template. yes, id has actual id.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't prevent the default submission event from happening.

```
$(document).on('click','#delete',function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  ..
});
```

Comment: That did not seem to do anything.